# Count amount of answers in a row

Tags: r

I would like to create a column that counts the number of responses. However, the condition is that no 4 and no NA are counted. Numbers like 2 and 3 only count with the value 1. For example, if a person has the answers 1, 3, 4, and NA it adds up to 2.

I am grateful for your help!

```
id <- c("agb", "efr", "h3z", "h8r", "p9o", "tr5", "g1f", "l95" )
c1 <- c(1:3, NA, 4, 9, 4, 4)
c2 <- c(9, 4, 2, 2, 2, 7, 6, 5)
c3 <- c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 3, 3, 4)
c4 <- c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 3, 3, 4)
DF <- tibble(id, c1, c2, c3, c4)
```

The table should look like this:

```
id <- c("agb", "efr", "h3z", "h8r", "p9o", "tr5", "g1f", "l95" )
c1 <- c(1:3, NA, 4, 9, 4, 4)
c2 <- c(9, 4, 2, 2, 2, 7, 6, 5)
c3 <- c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 3, 3, 4)
c4 <- c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 3, 3, 4)
sum <- c(4,3,4,1,1,4,3,1)


DF2 <- tibble(id, c1, c2, c3, c4, sum)
DF2
```

I tried out nrow, length (did not work out) and I could write something with ifelse but this would be to complicated. the actual data set is much larger.

You can also just link a similar question with an answer.

Comment: I edited the question to change the definition of `DF` you had different values for `c1` in the two tables. I made everything consistent from `DF` to `DF2`.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Does someone knows how it would be if not only 4 but also 3 should be excluded?

Comment: In the accepted answer, use the following instead: `  mutate(result = rowSums(across(starts_with("c"), \(x) !x %in% c(3,4)), na.rm = TRUE))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another `dplyr` option:

```
DF2 |>
  mutate(result = rowSums(across(starts_with("c"), \(x) !x %in% 4), na.rm = TRUE))
# # A tibble: 8 × 7
#   id       c1    c2    c3    c4   sum result
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 agb       1     9     1     1     4      4
# 2 efr       2     4     1     1     3      3
# 3 h3z       3     2     1     1     4      4
# 4 h8r      NA     2    NA    NA     1      1
# 5 p9o       4     2    NA    NA     1      1
# 6 tr5       9     7     3     3     4      4
# 7 g1f       4     6     3     3     3      3
# 8 l95       4     5     4     4     1      1
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `dplyr` pipeline with `rowwise()` and then sum the number of entries that don't equal 4 (the `NA` will automatically not get counted if you use `na.rm=TRUE`).

```r
library(dplyr)

id <- c("agb", "efr", "h3z", "h8r", "p9o", "tr5", "g1f", "l95" )
c1 <- c(1:3, NA, 4, 9, 4, 4)
c2 <- c(9, 4, 2, 2, 2, 7, 6, 5)
c3 <- c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 3, 3, 4)
c4 <- c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 3, 3, 4)

DF <- tibble(id, c1, c2, c3, c4)

DF %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(sum = sum(!c_across(c1:c4) ==4, na.rm=TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 8 × 6
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   id       c1    c2    c3    c4   sum
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1 agb       1     9     1     1     4
#> 2 efr       2     4     1     1     3
#> 3 h3z       3     2     1     1     4
#> 4 h8r      NA     2    NA    NA     1
#> 5 p9o       4     2    NA    NA     1
#> 6 tr5       9     7     3     3     4
#> 7 g1f       4     6     3     3     3
#> 8 l95       4     5     4     4     1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You want to `replace` values of `4` with `NA` and calculate `rowSums` of the resulting `!is.na`. Using just base R without extra packages.

```
> transform(DF, sum=rowSums(!is.na(replace(DF, DF == 4, NA)[-1])))
   id c1 c2 c3 c4 sum
1 agb  1  9  1  1   4
2 efr  2  4  1  1   3
3 h3z  3  2  1  1   4
4 h8r NA  2 NA NA   1
5 p9o  4  2 NA NA   1
6 tr5  9  7  3  3   4
7 g1f  4  6  3  3   3
8 l95  4  5  4  4   1
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(DF)
structure(list(id = c("agb", "efr", "h3z", "h8r", "p9o", "tr5", 
"g1f", "l95"), c1 = c(1, 2, 3, NA, 4, 9, 4, 4), c2 = c(9, 4, 
2, 2, 2, 7, 6, 5), c3 = c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 3, 3, 4), c4 = c(1, 
1, 1, NA, NA, 3, 3, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was very helpful. Does someone knows how it would be if not only 4 but also 3 should be excluded?

Comment: @Laura31 Just do `DF == 4 | DF == 4 | DF == ...`